# RC6 key generator not available

Tags: java, cryptography

I would try to use RC6 algorithm but i have an error:

**RC6 KeyGenerator not available**

How can i obtain the keygenerator of the rc6?

Exception in thread "main" java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: RC6 KeyGenerator not available
    at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.(KeyGenerator.java:169)
    at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyGenerator.java:223)
    at RC6.encrypt(RC6.java:27)
    at RC6.main(RC6.java:16)

```
import javax.crypto.spec.*;
import java.security.*;
import javax.crypto.*;

public class Main
{
   private static String algorithm = "RC6";

   public static void main(String []args) throws Exception {
      String toEncrypt = "The shorter you live, the longer you're dead!";

      System.out.println("Encrypting...");
      byte[] encrypted = encrypt(toEncrypt, "password");

      System.out.println("Decrypting...");
      String decrypted = decrypt(encrypted, "password");

      System.out.println("Decrypted text: " + decrypted);
   }

   public static byte[] encrypt(String toEncrypt, String key) throws Exception {
      // create a binary key from the argument key (seed)
      SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom(key.getBytes());
      KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance(algorithm);
      kg.init(sr);
      SecretKey sk = kg.generateKey();

      // create an instance of cipher
      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);

      // initialize the cipher with the key
      cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sk);

      // enctypt!
      byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(toEncrypt.getBytes());

      return encrypted;
   }

   public static String decrypt(byte[] toDecrypt, String key) throws Exception {
      // create a binary key from the argument key (seed)
      SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom(key.getBytes());
      KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance(algorithm);
      kg.init(sr);
      SecretKey sk = kg.generateKey();

      // do the decryption with that key
      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
      cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sk);
      byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(toDecrypt);

      return new String(decrypted);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RC6 is not an algorithm that is provided by one of the Oracle security providers. The providers provide the algorithm implementations that are behind `Cipher` and indeed `KeyGenerator`.

This should work, after adding the Bouncy Castle provider .jar in the classpath:

```
static {
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
}
```

---

You may also need to install the unlimited cryptography files in your JRE folder.

Comment: Hi Marteen, thank you for your answer.  Yes, i already installed the unlimited cryptography. I've downloaded and put the jar of Bouncy Castle from here https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html  and then i put the line Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider()) in the main. But now i have this error (at decrypt line): **pad block corrupted** Why? Something wrong?

Comment: I don't know what is wrong. This could be using the wrong key or a change of the ciphertext. On my system your code above works correctly. Note that RC6 is a block cipher. You need to make sure you use the correct *mode of operation* and IV as Java and BC providers tend to favor ECB mode, which is not secure. But that's something to worry about after you get it working I suppose.

Comment: I was distracted, sorry, in the decryption there is another keyGenerator. Thank you so much Marteen!

Comment: Ah, looking at the code you seem to use a seed for the `SecureRandom` which is why it works on my machine. **Do not do this**. Not all implementations will generate the same value that way, so you may lose all your data if you encrypt it that way. Just use `new SecureRandom()` and never expect it to generate the same values.